# Neural Network giving wrong outputs

Tags: delphi, neural-network

I am trying to get my first neural network working, though no matter what I do, the network never seems to get to the correct answer.

Here is the output after the network reached an MSE of 0.0001

```
0 XOR 0 = 0.0118003716248665

1 XOR 1 = 0.994320073237859

1 XOR 0 = 0.818618888320916

0 XOR 1 = 0.985995457430471
```

The problem: these answers are incorrect.

I create a network with 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons, and 1 output, the XOR problem has been solved using the same amounts, so that possibility is ruled out (I guess).

As a side note, I converted this code from a C# example found on another site, the C# code executes and works perfectly, so this is most likely a logic error or miscalculation somewhere :/

Now, unfortunately I have been totally unable to find the relevant piece of code leading up to the error, so I am going to have to post the entire code involving the Network here (sorry).

Edit: The UpdateWeights() function is the Back propagation, just thought I'd put this here in-case someone didn't catch it, the rest of the names and stuff is pretty understandable.

```
unit NeuralNetwork_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Math;

type TDoubleArray = array of Double;
type TDouble2DArray = array of TDoubleArray;

type TNeuralNetwork = class(TObject)
private
  numInput, numHidden, numOutput : Integer;
  inputs, hBiases, hSums, hOutputs, oBiases, oSums, Outputs, oGrads, hGrads, hPrevBiasesDelta, oPrevBiasesDelta : TDoubleArray;
  ihWeights, hoWeights, ihPrevWeightsDelta, hoPrevWeightsDelta : TDouble2DArray;
public
  constructor Create(NumInputs, NumHiddens, NumOutputs : Integer);
  procedure SetWeights(weights : TDoubleArray);
  function GetWeights : TDoubleArray;
  function GetOutputs : TDoubleArray;
  function ComputeOutputs( xvalues : TDoubleArray) : TDoubleArray;
  function SigmoidFunction( X : Double) : Double;
  function HyperTanFunction( X: Double) : Double;
  procedure UpdateWeights( tValues : TDoubleArray ; learn, mom : Double);
  function Train( TrainData : TDouble2DArray ; MaxEpochs : Integer ; LearningRate, Momentum, DesiredError : Double) : Double;
  function WeightCount : Integer;
  procedure Shuffle(Seq : array of Integer);
  function MeanSquaredError(TrainData : TDouble2DArray) : Double;
end;

type THelper = class(TObject)
public
  function MakeMatrix( Rows, Cols : Integer) : TDouble2DArray;
  function Error(tValues, yValues : array of Double) : Double;
end;


implementation

uses NetworkInterface_u;

constructor TNeuralNetwork.Create(NumInputs, NumHiddens, NumOutputs : Integer);
var
  Helper : THelper;
begin
  Helper := THelper.Create;
  numInput := NumInputs;
  numHidden := NumHiddens;
  numOutput := NumOutputs;

  SetLength(inputs,numInput);
  ihWeights := Helper.MakeMatrix(numInput, numHidden);
  SetLength(hBiases,numHidden);
  SetLength(hSums, numHidden);
  SetLength(hOutputs, numHidden);
  howeights := Helper.makeMatrix(numHidden, numOutput);
  SetLength(oBiases,numOutput);
  SetLength(oSums, numOutput);
  SetLength(Outputs, numOutput);
  SetLength(oGrads,numOutput);
  SetLength(hGrads,numHidden);
  ihPrevWeightsDelta := Helper.makeMatrix(numInput,numHidden);
  SetLength(hPrevBiasesDelta,numHidden);
  hoPrevWeightsDelta := Helper.makeMatrix(numHidden,numOutput);
  SetLength(oPrevBiasesDelta,numOutput);
end;

    unit NeuralNetwork_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Math;

type TDoubleArray = array of Double;
type TDouble2DArray = array of TDoubleArray;

type TNeuralNetwork = class(TObject)
private
  numInput, numHidden, numOutput : Integer;
  inputs, hBiases, hSums, hOutputs, oBiases, oSums, Outputs, oGrads, hGrads, hPrevBiasesDelta, oPrevBiasesDelta : TDoubleArray;
  ihWeights, hoWeights, ihPrevWeightsDelta, hoPrevWeightsDelta : TDouble2DArray;
public
  constructor Create(NumInputs, NumHiddens, NumOutputs : Integer);
  procedure SetWeights(weights : TDoubleArray);
  function GetWeights : TDoubleArray;
  function GetOutputs : TDoubleArray;
  function ComputeOutputs( xvalues : TDoubleArray) : TDoubleArray;
  function SigmoidFunction( X : Double) : Double;
  function HyperTanFunction( X: Double) : Double;
  procedure UpdateWeights( tValues : TDoubleArray ; learn, mom : Double);
  function Train( TrainData : TDouble2DArray ; MaxEpochs : Integer ; LearningRate, Momentum, DesiredError : Double) : Double;
  function WeightCount : Integer;
  procedure Shuffle( var Seq : array of Integer);
  function MeanSquaredError(TrainData : TDouble2DArray) : Double;
end;

type THelper = class(TObject)
public
  function MakeMatrix( Rows, Cols : Integer) : TDouble2DArray;
  function Error(tValues, yValues : array of Double) : Double;
end;


implementation

uses NetworkInterface_u;

constructor TNeuralNetwork.Create(NumInputs, NumHiddens, NumOutputs : Integer);
var
  Helper : THelper;
begin
  Helper := THelper.Create;
  numInput := NumInputs;
  numHidden := NumHiddens;
  numOutput := NumOutputs;

  SetLength(inputs,numInput);
  ihWeights := Helper.MakeMatrix(numInput, numHidden);
  SetLength(hBiases,numHidden);
  SetLength(hSums, numHidden);
  SetLength(hOutputs, numHidden);
  howeights := Helper.makeMatrix(numHidden, numOutput);
  SetLength(oBiases,numOutput);
  SetLength(oSums, numOutput);
  SetLength(Outputs, numOutput);
  SetLength(oGrads,numOutput);
  SetLength(hGrads,numHidden);
  ihPrevWeightsDelta := Helper.makeMatrix(numInput,numHidden);
  SetLength(hPrevBiasesDelta,numHidden);
  hoPrevWeightsDelta := Helper.makeMatrix(numHidden,numOutput);
  SetLength(oPrevBiasesDelta,numOutput);
end;

procedure TNeuralNetwork.SetWeights(weights : TDoubleArray);
var
  numWeights : Integer;
  i, k, j : Integer;
begin
  numWeights := (numInput * numHidden) + (numHidden * numOutput) + numHidden + numOutput;
  if High(weights) <> numWeights then
  begin
    Raise Exception.Create('The Weights Array Length Does Not match The Total Number Of Weights And Biases  -  ' + IntToStr(numWeights));
  end;

  k := 0;

  for i := 0 to numInput-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to numHidden-1 do
    begin
      ihWeights[i][j] := weights[k];
      Inc(k);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    hBiases[i] := weights[k];
    Inc(k);
  end;

  for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to numOutput-1 do
    begin
      hoWeights[i][j] := weights[k];
      Inc(k);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to numOutput-1 do
  begin
    oBiases[i] := weights[k];
    Inc(k);
  end;
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.GetWeights : TDoubleArray;
var
  numWeights : Integer;
  k, i, j : Integer;
begin
  numWeights := (numInput * numHidden) + (numHidden * numOutput) + numHidden + numOutput;
  SetLength(Result,numWeights);
  k := 0;

  for i := 0 to Length(ihWeights)-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Length(ihWeights[0])-1 do
    begin
      Result[k] := ihWeights[i][j];
      Inc(k);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(hBiases)-1 do
  begin
    Result[k] := hBiases[i];
    Inc(k);
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(hoWeights)-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Length(hoWeights[0])-1 do
    begin
      Result[k] := hoWeights[i][j] ;
      Inc(k);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(oBiases)-1 do
  begin
    Result[k] := oBiases[i];
    Inc(k);
  end;
end;

function TNeuralnetwork.GetOutputs : TDoubleArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, numOutput-1);
  Result := Outputs;
end;

Function TNeuralNetwork.ComputeOutputs( xValues : TDoubleArray) : TDoubleArray;
var
  i, j : Integer;
begin
  if Length(xvalues) <> numInput then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Inputs Array Does Not Match Neural Network Inputs Count = Array ' + IntToStr(Length(xValues)) + '  Input Count ' + IntToStr(numInput));
  end;

  for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    hSums[i] := 0.0;
  end;
  for i := 0 to numOutput-1 do
  begin
    oSums[i] := 0.0;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(xValues)-1 do
  begin
    inputs[i] := xValues[i];
  end;

  for j := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    for i := 0 to numInput-1 do
    begin
      hSums[j] := hSums[j] + (inputs[i]*ihWeights[i][j]);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    hSums[i] := hSums[i] + hBiases[i];
  end;

  for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
  begin
    hOutputs[i] := HyperTanFunction(hSums[i]);
  end;

  for j := 0 to numOutput-1 do
  begin
    for i := 0 to numHidden-1 do
    begin
      oSums[j] := oSums[j] + (hOutputs[i] * hoWeights[i][j]);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to numOutput-1 do
  begin
    oSums[i] := oSums[i] + oBiases[i];
  end;

  for i := 0 to numOutput-1 do
  begin
    Outputs[i] := HyperTanFunction(oSums[i]);
  end;

  Result := Outputs;
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.SigmoidFunction(X : Double) : Double;
begin
  if x < -45.0 then
    Result := 0
  else if x > 45.0 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 1.0 / (1.0 + Exp(-x));
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.HyperTanFunction( X : Double) : Double;
begin
  if x < -45.0 then
    Result := -1
  else if x > 45.0 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := Tanh(X);
end;

procedure TNeuralNetwork.UpdateWeights(tValues : TDoubleArray ; learn, mom : Double);
var
  i, j : Integer;
  derivative, sum, delta,X  : Double;
begin
  if Length(tValues) <> numOutput then
  begin
    Raise Exception.Create('Target Values Not Same Length As Output = ' + IntToStr(Length(tValues)) + ' - Outputcount = ' + IntToStr(numOutput));
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(oGrads)-1 do
  begin
    derivative := (1 - outputs[i]) * outputs[i];
    oGrads[i] := derivative * (tValues[i] - outputs[i]);
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(hGrads)-1 do
  begin
    derivative := (1 - hOutputs[i]) * (1 + hOutputs[i]);
    sum := 0;
    for j := 0 to numOutput-1 do
    begin
      X := oGrads[j] * hoWeights[i][j];
      sum := sum + X;
    end;
    hGrads[i] := derivative * sum;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(ihWeights)-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Length(ihWeights[0])-1 do
    begin
      delta := learn * hGrads[j] * inputs[i];
      ihWeights[i][j] := ihWeights[i][j] + delta;
      ihWeights[i][j] := ihWeights[i][j] + (mom * ihPrevWeightsDelta[i][j]);
      ihPrevWeightsDelta[i][j] := delta;
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(hBiases)-1 do
  begin
    delta := learn * hGrads[i] * 1.0;
    hBiases[i] := hBiases[i] + delta;
    hBiases[i] := hBiases[i] + (mom * hPrevBiasesDelta[i]);
    hPrevBiasesDelta[i] := delta;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(hoWeights)-1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Length(hoWeights[0])-1 do
    begin
      delta := learn * oGrads[j] * hOutputs[i];
      hoWeights[i][j] := hoWeights[i][j] + delta;
      hoWeights[i][j] := hoWeights[i][j] + (mom * hoPrevWeightsDelta[i][j]);
      hoPrevWeightsDelta[i][j] := delta;
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(oBiases)-1 do
  begin
    delta := learn * oGrads[i] * 1.0;
    oBiases[i] := oBiases[i] + delta;
    oBiases[i] := oBiases[i] + (mom * oPrevBiasesDelta[i]);
    oPrevBiasesDelta[i] := delta;
  end;
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.Train( TrainData : TDouble2DArray ; MaxEpochs : Integer ; LearningRate, Momentum, DesiredError : Double) : Double;
var
  Epoch, I, Idx, c : Integer;
  xValues : TDoubleArray;
  tValues : TDoubleArray;
  Sequence : Array of Integer;
  MeanSquaredErrorr : Double;
  Helper : THelper;
begin
  Epoch := 0;
  SetLength(xValues,numInput);
  SetLength(tValues,numOutput+1);
  SetLength(Sequence,Length(TrainData));

  for I := 0 to Length(Sequence)-1 do
    Sequence[I] := I;

  Shuffle(Sequence);
  
  while Epoch < MaxEpochs do
  begin
    frmNetworkInterface.redTraining.Lines.Add('Current Epoch - ' + IntToStr(Epoch) + ' : error = ' + FloatToStr(MeanSquaredErrorr) + ' and Desired Error is = ' + FloatToStr(DesiredError));
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    MeanSquaredErrorr := MeanSquaredError(TrainData);
    if MeanSquaredErrorr < DesiredError then
      Break;
    for I := 0 to Length(TrainData)-1 do
    begin
      Idx := Sequence[i];
      xValues := Copy(TrainData[Idx],0,numInput);
      tValues := Copy(TrainData[Idx],numInput,numOutput);
      ComputeOutputs(xValues);
      UpdateWeights(tValues,LearningRate,Momentum);
    end;
    Inc(Epoch);
    Result := MeanSquaredErrorr;
  end;
end;

procedure TNeuralNetwork.Shuffle( var Seq : array of Integer);
var
  I, R, Tmp : Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Length(Seq)-1 do
  begin
    R := RandomRange(i,Length(Seq));
    Tmp := Seq[i];
    Seq[R] := Seq[I];
    Seq[I] := Tmp;
  end;
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.MeanSquaredError(TrainData : TDouble2DArray) : Double;
var
  sumSquaredError, err : Double;
  xValues, tValues, yValues : TDoubleArray;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
  sumSquaredError := 0;
  SetLength(xValues,numInput);
  SetLength(tvalues,numOutput);

  for I := 0 to Length(TrainData)-1 do
  begin
    xValues := Copy(TrainData[I],0,numInput);
    tValues := Copy(TrainData[I],numInput,numOutput);
    yValues := ComputeOutputs(xValues);
    for J := 0 to numOutput-1 do
    begin
      err := tValues[j] - yValues[j];
      sumSquaredError := sumSquaredError + (err * err);
    end;
  end;
  Result := sumSquaredError / Length(TrainData);
end;

function TNeuralNetwork.WeightCount : Integer;
begin
  Result := (numInput * numHidden) + (numHidden * numOutput) + numHidden + numOutput;
end;

function THelper.MakeMatrix(Rows, Cols : Integer) : TDouble2DArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result,Rows,Cols);
end;

function THelper.Error(tValues : array of Double ; yValues : array of Double) : Double;
var
  sum : Double;
  i : Integer;
begin
  sum := 0.0;
  for i := 0 to High(tValues)-1 do
  begin
    sum := sum + ((tValues[i] - yValues[i]) * (tValues[i] - yValues[i]));
  end;
  Result := Sqrt(sum);
end;


end.
```

I have been through this code nearly a hundred times now, and no answer comes to light, no logic error or miscalculation found, however, as I know the C# example works, this should too.

EDIT :
Observation: it seems to me, whenever the second value I pass in is 1, the network automatically makes the output way too big (values of the weights involved with the second input are way too large for my tastes?), hence 1 XOR 1 is wrong, because the second value is 1 (see the data above).

EDIT :
Here is the initial weights of one network i just ran (2 input, 2 hidden, 1 output)

> ```
>  Initial Weight0 - 0.0372207039175555
>
>  Initial Weight1 - 0.01092082898831
>
>  Initial Weight2 - 0.0755334409791976
>
>  Initial Weight3 - 0.0866588755254634
>
>  Initial Weight4 - 0.0626101282471791
>
>  Initial Weight5 - 0.0365478269639425
>
>  Initial Weight6 - 0.0724486718699336
>
>  Initial Weight7 - 0.0320405319170095
>
>  Initial Weight8 - 0.0680674042692408
> ```

And after 132 Epochs (an error of 0.001)

> ```
>  Final Weight 0 = 0.432341693850932
>
>  Final Weight 1 = 0.338041456780997
>
>  Final Weight 2 = 1.0096817584107
>
>  Final Weight 3 = 0.839104863469981
>
>  Final Weight 4 = -0.275763414588823
>
>  Final Weight 5 = -0.171414938983027
>
>  Final Weight 6 = 1.26394969109634
>
>  Final Weight 7 = 0.998915778388676
>
>  Final Weight 8 = 0.549501870374428
> ```

EDIT: So a new development has come to light, an error when passing in the TrainingData caused it to identify 1 XOR 1 = 1, however, after fixing this error, the network cant converge on an answer (ran 100 networks, 10 thousand epochs each) the lowest MSE (Mean Squared Error) I got was

> Current Epoch - 9999 : error = 0.487600332892658 and Desired Error is = 0.001

I logged the input and outputs sent into the network on each epoch of training and identified that they all were correct now, so now it just seems that the network is unable to solve the problem?

Also, I'm updating the code to my most recent version. (08/26/2015)

Whats new in this code :

> - Fixed Copy indices that was 1 instead of 0.
> - Can confirm that the Inputs and Desired outputs is correctly copied now.

EDIT : The MSE of the network is actually INCREASING now, here is the initial error :

> 0.467486419821747,

and after 10000 Epochs,

> 0.487600332892658,

the overall error increased with

> 0.020113913070917

... This leads me to believe that either my Training procedure, or the UpdateWeights procedure is faulty...

EDIT : Another observation I made, is that the Mean Square Error of the network caps out on 2.5 ( when running an insanely long training session to make it move that much ) The damn MSE is going up instead of going down??

EDIT : Another observation of output of the network whilst training

> Current Epoch - 233 : error = 0.802251346201161 and Desired Error is = 0.0001
>
> Current Epoch - 234 : error = 1.24798705066641 and Desired Error is = 0.0001
>
> Current Epoch - 235 : error = 2.47206076545025 and Desired Error is = 0.0001
>
> Current Epoch - 236 : error = 2.49999999811955 and Desired Error is = 0.0001

A radical jump from 1.24 was seen to 2.49 , The network is clearly getting errors in the functions having to do with either training or weight changing.

Comment: Are you **sure** that your Delphi code faithfully reproduces calculations in the C# code?  Have you verified that the outputs of a single neuron in C# and D for the same input are the same?  If so, then unless someone can spot an obvious error in your Delphi code, maybe you'll need to write some logging code into both versions and trace them side-by-side to see where they diverge.

Comment: @MartynA the problem is just that, the outputs aren't the same, yet they are programmed the same ( I made a lot more than triple sure), if it would help, I can link to the c# code, or post it on here as well? As far as I can tell ( based on experimentation) the network in c# and delphi trains successfully, with the MSE constantly declining, but my outputs differ from that of the c#

Comment: Let me check that and I'll get back to you, never thought of this possibility

Comment: Just confirmed that the arrays work exactly the same [row] [column] in both languages

Comment: > I Create A network with 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons, and 1 output, the XOR problem has been solved using the same amounts, so that possibility is ruled out ( I guess )

Regarding this, no, this is not ruled out. Just because you can find the correct weights by hand, it does not mean backprop can find them too. It may depend on your metaparameter settings. I'd suggest you to try 3 hidden neurons to rule this out (it is waaay easier for backprop). Then you'll know if your code has a problem.

Comment: Ran it with 3 hidden neurons, here is the output : 1 XOR 1 = 0.995169394600612 (totally wrong) | 0 XOR 0 = 0.0123425655015052 | 1 XOR 0 = 0.805605738953139 | 0 XOR 1 = 0.985832738832591

Comment: I added some new information to the main question, just an observation I made...

Comment: Added additional info regarding the weights in the main question

Comment: Do some debugging. Don't just look at the code and despair. Log output. Compare. In short, learn how to debug.

Comment: Did you realize that the shuffle method is just burning time and did not change the array you pass in as argument?

Comment: I realize that, still wanted to fix that

Comment: @David we have yet to learn about debugging in school ( don't think they really handle the subject much) but as this is extracurricular, I will take up one or two books regarding efficient logging and debugging ( thanks for making me see that I don't really debug/log as much as I should be)

Comment: @KazutoKirigaya I really commend you on your attitude. It's nice to come across someone so keen and hungry to learn. It's true that debugging is the great untaught skill. Hard to find good textbooks on the topic.

Comment: Thanks :) I have always been big on learning In  general, but programming has always been my favorite, and more specifically in that field, artificial intelligence as a whole, so I'm trying very hard to learn all I can about anything I can :D

Comment: Code site you say, I will make sure to Google it, I'm not stingy and will shell out a few dollars if it means I'm more efficient in the process, as for the bugs you mentioned, thanks! I will be sure to fix them

Comment: Before continuing fix the two obvious bug first `Copy(TrainData[Idx],1,numInput);` is wrong, should be 0 instead of 1. You were training with the second input and the output values!

Comment: I have fixed that bug just now, output still not correct though, but im sure that  it will save me a lot of headaches in the future... Thanks

Comment: Updated the main question with the latest situation..

Comment: Bump ( sorry if this isn't allowed )

Answer (score 0):

I suspect from your code that the original works in degrees (because you use constants like -45.0) and Delphi works in radians, so wherever you have 45 you need (PI/4) etc. It is likely that during training you are running out of epochs before you reach the accuracy required because the functions can go out of range.

Comment: Okay this makes some sense to me.... So say perhaps I make this functions to return only the raw output (not adjusting it in anyway eg. Just the sigmodal of the passed in value, would that be a decent fix for this problem? I will test this out and come back to you asap.)

Comment: @Kazuto Kirigaya - I don't think so, but I am not sure. The whole point is that that each function can return data far outside its range (because value in degrees are MUCH bigger than the corresponding values in radians) so removing the bounds altogether would just make matters worse, I would have thought.

Comment: @Dsm that is not the problem here. The 45 has nothing to do with degrees! It has to do with numeric precision. Your assumption is based on the fact that a value like 45 seems familiar in the context of degrees, but is unfortunately wrong. The original project in visual studio magazine also used radians.

Comment: So instead of just saying 45 I should be doing what calculation exactly ( like 45/(pi/4)?  Sorry for asking but I'm quite unfamiliar with this subject (degrees and radians)

Comment: PI = 3.141597... 360 degrees (one full circle) = 2 * PI radians, 360 in the original program equates to about 6.28 radians. So 45 degress (=360/8) equates to PI/4 (=2*PI/8). So for a start whever you see 45, replace it by PI/4. If you had 90 you would replace it by PI/2 and so on. Whether that is the total answer I cannot say. I am not really familiar with neural networks. You may need to multiply your parameters by (PI/180.0) as well. I suggest you Google radians.

Comment: @jasper so it's not wrong then? Well scratching that off my list :/ damn, I will continue to log some of the code and post the results on my Mai  question till we can solve the main problem!

Comment: @jasper Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Updated the main question with new information/developments